# Hyperledger Fabric SDK Go Installation Error. What is going wrong here and How to fix it?

Tags: linux, makefile, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm trying to install Hyperledger Fabric SDK for Go Language.. How do I fix this problem?

> After I tried the "make" command, this error shows up.
>
> Go Version- 1.11.4
>
> docker Version- 18.09
>
> docker-compose Version- 1.13

I'm following instructions mentioned in this Tutorial :-[Hyperledger Fabric SDK GO Tutorial](https://chainhero.io/2018/03/tutorial-build-blockchain-app-2/)

and this error shows up after I install "libltdl-dev" as mentioned in the Tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do

make depend

This will install all the dependencies . And also check for the check_lint.sh file.

Comment: I did that before running 'make'. While that should have installed the dependencies, It just showed me the list of dependencies that had to be installed and then stopped. I installed those dependencies manually from the specified sources and then ran 'make' which gave me this error.

Comment: check the dependencies for the target in line 189 in makefile .

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's what I figured out the problem was - Hyperledger Fabric can only be used in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS. This is why it wasn't working on my PC which had 18.4 LTS. Just wondering when Hyperledger Support will be extended to 19.x since that is out already!